# Drawing World map on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, administrative-boundaries

I want to plot data from a project on a world map using choropleths. The data is at country level, and I am using ArcMap 10.2.

I had started by adding **World countries (generalized)** from ArcGIS Online, which essentially freezes the entire tool making unusable.

How can I import that dataset locally?

Can you point me to some tutorial/resource to draw a nice-looking world map with ArcMap?

Comment: first tip is make sure to use the correct projection for the world, something like Eckert IV or the like.

Comment: I am using Winkel Tripel.

Comment: Thats a good choice =)

Answer (score 1):

[Global Administrative Areas](http://www.gadm.org/version2) free download, in pretty high detail. The single layer download sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Is this layer generalized enough to look nice on a world scale? The layers I found so far are way too detailed.

Comment: Using this tool: http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001v00000006000000 You can generalize to whatever degree you feel works for you!

Answer (score 0):

When ArcGIS line adds data these days, it's actually a series of layers, with settings that uses different shapefiles with different levels of detail, depending on how far zoomed in you are. Export the one that is visible when you are looking at the whole globe, and work with that. If that's not detailed enough, zoom in on ESRI's map a bit and export whatever file is visible.